# Reverting to previous commit non-destructively

Tags: git

We need to revert to a prior commit, but because changes since that commit have been pushed into production we can't destroy repo history with `git reset`.

Reverting to past commits has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095/165673) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2007662/165673), but neither provides a satisfactory non-destructive solution.

We tried to follow [@Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2007682/165673) by checking out the previous commit in a separate branch, but when we tried to merge it into master we get an "Already up-to-date." message and nothing happens.

```
$ git checkout 0766c053 -b reverted
$ git checkout master
$ git merge reverted
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: What exactly is unsatisfactory in `git revert`? Seems it'd be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Amadan- `git revert` only reverts one specific commit, ignoring any commits made since then. We need to revert back *to* a previous commit. Git doesn't have a `git revert --to` function.

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1470452/240443

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it, thanks to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11743042/165673) from @Amadan and to @BobSlocum, bashful and mysterious, who gave a fine [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21717713/165673) and then deleted it and went away...

Here's all you have to do:

```
git revert --no-commit 0766c053..HEAD
```

This will revert everything from the HEAD back to the commit hash. (The `--no-commit` flag lets git revert all the commits at once, instead of littering history with messages for each commit in the range.)

Comment: @Amadan's link did a better job of explaining what I said. Didn't want to look like I was trying to shark his glory:)

Comment: No worries. :) +1, as you wrote out a proper answer. Also, maybe noteworthy is a general syntax: if you want to revert everything from X to Y, `X^..Y` works. (`X..Y` will revert everything *since* X, not X itself).

Answer (score 0):

Someone can no doubt cook up a `git reset` sequence to do it, but here's the direct route:

```
git checkout -B master $(
        git commit-tree -p master -m - 0766c053^{tree} 
)
```

and `git commit --amend` it to add a commit message.