# Git pull old commits

Tags: git, github, git-pull

How do I git pull something on a previous commit on a repository? I'm following a guide in which half of the code was outdated and the other half is not. So I need to send that one half back to its previous state on my local files. Or should I be using checkout? I found the commit I think I need but I cannot get it to replace my files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007662/rollback-to-an-old-commit-using-git)?

Comment: Yes, I want to do the equivalent of a git pull I think. It is not my respository and I don't intend on ever pushing my changes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git log` to find the SHA of the commit you want to roll back to, then:

```
git checkout <SHA of commit>
```

To change the contents of the commit, just type

```
git rm [-options] <Path to file (or directory)>
```

Then

```
git commit --amend
git push origin master //Optional
```

to complete your changes.

Answer (score 0):

To restore some files to a previous state -say to commit with sha1 `abc`-, you could do

```
git checkout abc -- file1 file2 dir1
git commit -am "Rolled back some files"
```

Doing so will add a new commit on your current branch, with those files in their old state.