# Switching current work in master branch to a new branch (in git)

Tags: git, branch

I just discovered I did a big mistake. I made changes in the `master` branch for several days when I had intended to do it in the `feature-x` branch.

How do I switch all changes in the current branch (master) to `feature-x` branch?
I'd also like to have `master` branch in a clean state. (When I do `git status` on master, it should show no changes, but when I do `git status` on feature-x it should show all changes I had so far).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can

- [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) (to save the work in progress on master)
- [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) your commits from master to `feature-x`.
  See "[How to cherry pick a range of commits and merge into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309)".
- [reset `master` to an older commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14873290/6309).
  (`reset --hard`)
- checkout `feature-x` and `git stash pop`, for your git status to get back all the current changes

That assumes that *all* your last commits on `master` were for `feature-x`.
If those commits were mixed with some for master, as [hoppjerka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1513411/hoppjerka) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087194/switching-current-work-in-master-branch-to-a-new-branch-in-git/27087208?noredirect=1#comment42682720_27087208), you would use an interactive rebase:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i {master@"3 days ago"}'
```

You would drop the ones you don't want on master.

---

> I have to say I haven't commited yet. All the changes currently in the master are showing in git status. So I only need to move the changes

Then

```
git stash
git checkout feature-x
git stash pop
```

Comment: If you only want to remove a few commits from master you can do 'git rebase -i {master@"3 days ago"}' and remove the commits you have moved to feature-x.

Comment: @hoppjerka true. I have included your suggestion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I have to say I haven't commited yet. All the changes currently in the master are showing in `git status`. So I only need to move the changes. I dont think I need to cherry pick. .. I think I only need to `git stash`, `git branch` and `git stash pop`.

Comment: @bodacydo I agree. I have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks you sir. This was easy. :) Upvoted & accepted. I'll refer to your answer in the future as well when I've commited and then realized branches weren't switched. Happens often.

Comment: Oh goodness, I think I just lost 2 days of work..... I did `git stash`, `git checkout -b feature-x`, `git stash pop`. Then I did `git status` - verified that changes are there. Then I `git checkout master`. Then I did `git status` and saw the changes in the master branch, but since I thought they were already saved in feature-x branch, I did `git checkout -f` to throw away local changes in master branch. Then I `git checkout feature-x` and all the changes are gone in `feature-x` branch as well........... whooooops. what did i do wrong?

Comment: @bodacydo you never added or committed those changes. Try git reflog to see if the stash might still be accessible there.

Comment: @bodacydo git stash apply the SHA1 previously displayed by git stash pop

Comment: trying now!! thanks (although i'm seeing only `dcff78b... HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to feature-x` and `dcff78b... HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from feature-x to master` messages)

Comment: @bodacydo here you go! I would still advise you to make a commit (even an intermediate one), or a backup of some sort ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Doing a commit now. I thought changes were per-branch. So when I see changes in `git status` in master, they're unrelated to changes in feature-x. Could you comment why `git commit -f` in master cleaned up all the changes in feature-x, too? I think I don't understand how git works fully yet

Comment: @bodacydo I think the checkout -f was the one which removed your local changes. But a local change is associated to your working tree, not to a branch. They are candidate to be added to the index, to then prepare the next commit. I would recommend following the quick tutorial https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1 to better understand git.

Comment: sorry it was `git checkout -f` I mistyped when i wrote `commit -f`. you're right. i get my mistake now. thanks for tutorial!