# Git reset --hard dont remove git merge errors

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

I treid to rebase my branch into another, but did something wrong which applied different patches to the same code, which resulted in alot of these:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
<<<<<<< HEAD
```

All over my project.

Now when I try to undo all of these I did `git reset --hard 44b76568` where `44b76568` is my latest commit before rebase. I got that my head was not at this commit, but nothing changed in my code. I still have

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
```

and other error codes, everywhere.

Comment: You might post your *exact commands*, if you have them available (e.g., in bash history).

Comment: tried `git checkout` to get your old version back? And, when there is conflict, git does not finish the rebase, I believe you could `git rebase --abort`

Comment: `git rebase --abort` only works if you are in the rebase process.  How do I get my bash history?

Comment: Perhaps the real problem here is that you've actually made a commit containing those conflict markers? If you have then no reset or checkout will get rid of them. Please check to ensure this isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which commit is ok, you could go back to it using `git checkout My_commit_ID .` - in your case, It could be `git checkout 44b76568 .`, if you are sure `44b76568` is stable (or maybe a previous one, if it still has errors)...

Maybe this post will help you:
[How to rollback to an old git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007662/rollback-to-an-old-git-commit-in-a-public-repo)

FYI - To know the hash of your commits, use `git log` command ([git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)).

Answer (score 1):

1. Open up your repository in Git GUI if you have it installed.
2. Go to `Repository` > `Visualize [BRANCHNAME] history`
3. Right-click on the commit you want to *reset to* and select `Reset...` from the context menu.
4. Select `Hard` to do a hard-reset. CAUTION: Local changes will be lost
5. Redo all changes thereafter.