# Reverting the working copy to an older commit?

Tags: git, github

I need to revert [this repository](https://github.com/superflycss/utilities-layout/) to the commit `e4ea7bf73124968e2f68012f77837df2046fd6e5`.  In other words I want to completely wipe all commits that come after that.

Based on one of the answers [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit) here's what I'm doing:

```
git clone git@github.com:superflycss/utilities-layout.git
cd utilities-layout

git reset e4ea7bf73124968e2f68012f77837df2046fd6e5 
# Moves pointer back to previous HEAD
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}

git commit -m "Revert to e4ea7bf73124968e2f68012f77837df2046fd6e5"

# Updates working copy to reflect the new commit
git reset --hard
```

At this point I'm thinking that I'm home free, but when I do an ls, all the files that were in the original clone are still there.  It's as if no revert has happened at all.  Thoughts?

Comment: Seems to me this question is a duplicate answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2007704/10936320

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want with the least change to what you are doing, switch to this sequence of commands:

```
git clone git@github.com:superflycss/utilities-layout.git
cd utilities-layout
```

(same so far, but then:)

```
git reset --hard e4ea7bf73124968e2f68012f77837df2046fd6e5
```

(note the addition of `--hard` here), then back to what you had before:

```
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
git commit -m "Revert to e4ea7bf73124968e2f68012f77837df2046fd6e5"
```

No additional `reset` is required after this, because the first `git reset` adjusted both your index and your work-tree (while also modifying the hash stored in your branch name).  The second `git reset` *only* modifies the hash stored in your branch name, readying you for the `git commit`.

Your original command sequence uses a `--mixed` reset for the first step.  This resets the index while writing a new hash, but leaves the work-tree untouched.  The second, soft, reset fixes the stored hash ID.  The third `git reset --hard` leaves *untracked* work-tree files untouched: these files became untracked at the first `git reset` and remained untracked since then.  In other words, since that first reset was `--mixed`, those work-tree files were never removed, and now won't be.

---

(Side note: I would probably achieve this with one `git read-tree` followed by one `git commit`, rather than multiple `git reset` commands. But this is a different strategy, and does not explain what happened with the method you were using.  Hence the answer above, which does explain it.)

Answer (score 2):

To revert to a specific commit you just need to

```
git reset --hard <COMMIT_HASH>
```

In case you want to update this change in remote

```
git push --force origin <BRANCH_NAME>
```

If you have untracked files have a look to

```
git clean
```

Comment: To remove all untracked files use `git clean -fdx` in the root directory of the repo. This will also delete untracked directories (d) and files named in .gitignore (x).