# Deleting Branch will remove all the data from that Branch

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I committed code into remote git (branch), I accidentally some unwanted large files and folders into the branch, later I removed those files and folders in the local again I committed into the git branch but before files and folders still in remote git branch.

give me suggestions I need to remove every unwanted file and folder from the remote branch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Revert a commit on remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473587/revert-a-commit-on-remote-branch)

Comment: Did you push your branch again?

Comment: Also, I think your question is missing some verbs. It's not clear what you did.