# How can I go back to specific commit without losing the commit history?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have cloned a lecture project from Github. The project is a finalized one and it contains multiple commit history eg: Lecture 1, Lecture2.

Using the software TortoiseGit, I am able to review the log of Git commits. 
What I am trying to do is that I need to review code of the same project from lecture 1 to lecture 7.

However, if I try to use reset hard/ check out to go back to specific commit, nothing seems to happen. The folders and files do not seem to change.

I read from the Net that using cleanup command could make it work. So I cleaned up. It indeed went back to the old version.
However, the commit history after this commit is missing. Then I cannot proceed.

Thank you in advance

Basic Procedures:

Init: at Lecture 7

Operation1 : Go back to Lecture 1

Operation 2: Go to Lecture 2

Operation 3: ....

Operation 7: go back to lecture 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rollback to an old Git commit in a public repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007662/rollback-to-an-old-git-commit-in-a-public-repo)

Answer (score 1):

You may checkout an earlier commit directly via:

```
# from your_branch
git checkout <SHA-1 has of earlier commit>
```

This will put Git into the detached HEAD state, where the HEAD points some earlier commit in the branch, but is not actually on a particular branch.  You may poke around and review the code, and when you are finished, return to your original branch via:

```
git checkout your_branch
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not solve my problem. After checkout, nothing happens. The files written after the commit still exist, for example I checkout to Lecture 3, materials in Lecture 7 still exist. It has only 1 master branch and I am working on it.