# Grab Git Commit, Make Changes, Then Re-Commit It

Tags: git, git-commit

I have not used Git extensively and so I usually end up searching for my answers to my Git questions online without much trouble. However yesterday I encountered a problem I haven't faced before and wasn't sure the correct Git way to go about it when searching online. Here's the problem I faced:

1. I committed some code that was not fully complete
2. My manager committed other changes not related to my code after my commit
3. Then he reverted my commit so my changes were no longer on master

Here in lies my problem, I need to grab my commit, make some changes and then re-commit them. **My question is this, what is the proper way to grab my commit changes that were reverted, edit them and then re-commit them?**

What I did: I solved my issue by pulling from master to get up to date, then went to the Bitbucket server and selected my commit, downloaded the files and copied those files back into the project. Then I proceeded to make changes. This allowed me to do git status and see those files were changed and also use git difftool to compare my changes with master before committing to ensure I want the changes I am committing.

I tried [checking out the commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007662/rollback-to-an-old-git-commit-in-a-public-repo) but then the files didn't end up showing up as modified and wasn't sure where to go from there... Was I supposed to branch from the commit, make changes on that branch and then merge it back into master?

Answer (score 2):

The master currently contains your changes and a commit that reverts them. While the current master doesn't contain your changes, the important thing is to remember that these commit aren't gone. The easiest thing would be to cherry-pick your original commit to the branch you're working on, complete the work and then `git commit --amend` your additional changes to create a commit with the full change.

Answer (score 0):

If your changes were removed from master you might need to check the reflog to find them.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Once you find your changes you can check them out, create a branch and merge them back into master.