# Git: I accidently did git checkout --​ . so all my changes are gone, how can I get them back?

Tags: git, github

The question is simple: I made a couple of changes in a branch, but I accidently erased them all by doing the command `git checkout -- .`. How can I undo this mistake?

Edit: I committed the changes before I deleted them

Comment: Unless you had committed the changes, they're gone now.

Comment: I had commited the changes

Comment: In that case you just need to check out whichever branch you committed those changes to.

Comment: then you can do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007662/rollback-to-an-old-git-commit-in-a-public-repo

Comment: The only difficulty is finding the commit to which you want to go back to.  For that, there's `git reflog`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+git+checkout