# Git how to revert to a certain commit, but keep all the commits I made

Tags: git

Suppose I have commits A-B-C-D-E-F. Note that all the commits have been pushed upstream.

I want to revert to commit D, but also want to keep commits E and F in the branch.

So what I want to do is to create a commit G, which will have the same contents as D. In the end my branch will look like A-B-C-D-E-F-G, with D=G.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can use `git revert E F`, but it will create two commits to revert each of E and F.

Comment: @choroba the sequence was just for illustration. There are actually many more commits where E and F are, so this wouldn't be a solution unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure why this isn't a solution if you have more than 2 commits. You can squash all the new ones, no?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rollback to an old Git commit in a public repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007662/rollback-to-an-old-git-commit-in-a-public-repo)

Answer (score 4):

You just have to take the exact content of `D`, and create a commit with that content :

```
# choose a. or b. :
# a. 'git restore' was added for this purpose in version 2.25,
#    and has options which are more explanatory (readable at least) :
git restore --source D --staged --worktree -- .

# b. for older gits, or for people enjoying more obscure commands, there is 'git read-tree' :
git read-tree D

# after that :
# confirm that the content you expect is staged, and commit :
git status
git commit
```

---

one word of caution: `git restore` with the `--worktree` option can delete files and discard modifications from files that aren't stored in `git` yet -- much like `git reset --hard`.

It is advised to use this command on a clean worktree, or at least check that you can throw away your current modifications.

Comment: `--source` is more readable than `-s`, when mentioning explanatoriness and readability.

Comment: Another way with the same principle: `git checkout D; git reset --soft F; git commit -m "Reverting E and F"`. Feel free to set a branch where you are standing at that point.

Comment: Need to get `git restore` into my toolbox.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think so. `git reset --soft` would just move the branch _pointer_ to `F` but the working tree and index would remain with what is in `D`. If you commit right after that you end up with `G` that follows `F` and that has the same content of `D`.

Comment: Nou problemo!!!